# Two Dimensional BVP

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am having a hard time in how someone could solve ${d^2V}/{d^2y^2}$+${d^2V}/{d^2x^2}$=0 with the following boundary conditions:

- V=0 when y=0,
- V=0 when y=a,
- V=$V_o$(y) when x=0,
- V->0 as x-> infinity

to prove that V(x,y)= (2$V_o$/$\pi$)*$tan^{-1}$((sin($\pi$y/a)/sinh($\pi$x/a))

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is there a typo in d^2V/d^2x^2+d^2V/d^2x^2=0? It seems the two terms you are adding together are identical and that seems odd. It might also help if you made it really clear what parameter or parameters your V depends on, perhaps by writing the line of Mathematica DSolve code you are trying to use.

Comment: Opps yes, let me fix that

Comment: Please show the Mathematica code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the desired solution is valid only for `v0` a constant.  Define

```
v = (2 v0[y]/Pi) ArcTan[Sin[Pi y/a]/Sinh[Pi x/a]];
```

Indeed, it satisfies the boundary conditions:

```
v /. y -> 0
(* 0 *)
v /. y -> a
(* 0 *)
FullSimplify[v /. x -> Infinity, a > 0]
(* 0 *)
Series[v, {x, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && x >= 0 && a > y > 0] // Normal
(* v0[y] *)
```

However,

```
FullSimplify[D[v, x, x] + D[v, y, y], a > 0 && x >= 0 && a > y > 0]
(* (a (-Cos[(2 π y)/a] + Cosh[(2 π x)/a]) Csch[(π x)/a]^4 
   (4 π Cos[(π y)/a] Sinh[(π x)/a] v0'[y] + a ArcTan[Csch[(π x)/a] Sin[(π y)/a]] 
   (-Cos[(2 π y)/a] + Cosh[(2 π x)/a]) v0''[y])
   /(2 π (a + a Csch[(π x)/a]^2 Sin[(π y)/a]^2)^2) *)
```

which in general equals `0` only for `v0'[y] == 0`.